# Why are certain words in Firefox missing from my webpages?

Tags: 14.04, firefox, text, html

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Dell XPS-12 laptop, in Mozilla Firefox, with no extensions running.

For some reason, Firefox has been taking sections of readable text out of the pages I've been visiting. It's happened on other ones as well, but this page is so simple that I thought it would be best to isolate the problem here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/why-shell.html

So down where it says "Procedures involving heavy-duty math operations, especially floating point arithmetic, arbitrary precision calculations, or complex numbers (use C++ or FORTRAN instead)", I can't actually see the "C++" or "FORTRAN" words - they're just not there. I opened up the Inspector and saw that the words were wrapped in  elements, but that shouldn't do anything, should it?

Anyone have any thoughts as to why this is happening?

Comment: Do you have `DejaVu Serif Italic` font installed? (that font is what is used to render on my fedora system anyway). Does it work in other browsers?

Comment: And it's only firefox issue ?

Comment: The text on this page has no associated font. Therefore Firefox will substitute the default font that you set in the Options. However, the words C++ and Fortran are between italic tags. If there is an italic version of your default font installed on your system, Firefox will use that; otherwise, I guess Firefox gets confused. So tell us what the default font is (Options/Content) and whether you have an italic version of that font installed. You may experiment with other default fonts, to see if the text reappears.

Comment: OP here, I installed the dejavu fonts package from Synaptic and restarted - worked like a charm. (It was a Firefox-only issue) Thanks guys!

Comment: @Jos you might want to convert your comments into an answer in order to allow the OP to accept one and mark the question as solved - and spread some rep points :D

Answer (score 0):

The text on this page has no associated font. Therefore Firefox will substitute the default font that you set in the Options. However, the words C++ and Fortran are between italic tags. If there is an italic version of your default font installed on your system, Firefox will use that; otherwise, I guess Firefox gets confused. Thetefore, install an italic version of the default font, or choose another default font (in Options/Content) and see if the text reappears.